# Django REST Framework 401 error with Vue3

Tags: html, django, vue.js

I am trying to get data from Django REST framework. However it returned 401, unless I refresh the entire page. The code is retrieved from a components, embed in a main Vue page.

[Here is how the page looks like. When I click the Menu it will show the component page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UT1C.png)

[error from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRcON.png)

Updated Vue3 Code

```
  mounted() {
    this.getUserInfo();
  },
  methods: {
    getUserInfo() {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      axios
        .get("/api/v2/user_info/", {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.users = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

Code from DJANGO Views.py

```
class User_Info_List(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User_Info.objects.all()
    serializer_class = User_InfoSerializer
```

I am giving up on figure out the 401 errors, introduced a refresh function at mounted, problem solved...

```js
  mounted: function () {
    if (location.href.indexOf("#reloaded") == -1) {
      location.href = location.href + "#reloaded";
      location.reload();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass authrization token headers of axios while calling the api if that is need autorized token

Like this

```
axios.get("/api/v2/user_info/" , { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`} })
   .then(response => {
      this.users = response.data;
   .catch((error) => {
       console.log(error)
   });
```

Let me know if you still have a question

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sanjay, thank you for your reply. I provided the token in the header, but the 401 error is still there. I attached a picture of the console if that helps. Thanks again!

Comment: The weird thing is if I include the token in the header, I always get 401 error. If I delete the header, then fresh the page, the data shall pop up.